# Как автоматически добавлять utm-метки ко всем ссылкам на странице

Tags: php, jquery

Есть сайт с внутренними и внешними ссылками. Как автоматически ко всем ссылкам на странице добавлять utm метки? Нужно чтобы данные utm меток передавались на внешние сайты.

Comment: Покажите код генерации ссылок. А так вам ни кто не поможет.

Comment: я не знаю код генерации ссылок. сайт на joomla Человек попадает на сайт по ссылке mysite.ru/?utm_content=1
Нужно чтобы при переходе по любым ссылкам на сайте в адресной строке сохранялось ?utm_content=1 
То есть для внешней ссылки gosite.ru автоматически дописалось gosite.ru?utm_content=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**: Изменил метод `translateLinkParam` таким образом, чтобы можно было указать несколько параметров для передачи и область действия:

```
translateLinkParam('foo, bar', document.getElementById('change-link-params'));
```

Также теперь учитывается наличие `hash` у ссылок, а уже имеющиеся параметры не будут дублироваться (их значение будет изменено).

Решение со слушателем события `click` оказалось далеко не идеальным - открытие ссылок через контекстное меню не учитывалось, а также, если внутри ссылки были вложенные элементы, нельзя было ориентироваться на `event.target.tagName`.

---

Можно модифицировать ссылки после загрузки страницы следующим образом:

```js
var translateLinkParam = (function() {
  var parseLink = function(link) {
      var
        linkObj = {
          path: link,
          hash: '',
          paramObj: {}
        },
        paramPos = linkObj.path.indexOf('?'),
        hashPos = linkObj.path.indexOf('#');

      if (hashPos > -1) {
        linkObj.hash = linkObj.path.substr(hashPos);
        linkObj.path = linkObj.path.substr(0, hashPos);
      }

      if (paramPos > -1) {
        linkObj.path
          .substr(paramPos + 1)
          .split('&')
          .forEach(function(param) {
            param = param.split('=');
            linkObj.paramObj[param[0]] = param[1];
          });

        linkObj.path = linkObj.path.substr(0, paramPos);
      }

      return linkObj;
    },
    addLinkParam = function(link, paramObj) {
      var linkObj = parseLink(link),
        paramString = '';

      Object.keys(paramObj).forEach(function(paramName) {
        linkObj.paramObj[paramName] = paramObj[paramName];
      });

      Object.keys(linkObj.paramObj).forEach(function(paramName) {
        if (paramString.length) {
          paramString += '&';
        }
        paramString += paramName + '=' + linkObj.paramObj[paramName];
      });

      return linkObj.path + (paramString ? '?' + paramString : '') + linkObj.hash;
    };

  return function(paramName, elem) {
    var locationParamObj = parseLink(window.location.href).paramObj,
      paramObj = {},
      linkSet = elem ? elem.getElementsByTagName('a') : document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
      i;

    paramName.split(',').forEach(function(paramName) {
      paramName = paramName.trim();
      if (locationParamObj[paramName]) {
        paramObj[paramName] = locationParamObj[paramName];
      }
    });

    if (Object.keys(paramObj).length) {
      for (i = 0; i < linkSet.length; i++) {
        linkSet[i].href = addLinkParam(linkSet[i].href, paramObj);
      }
    }
  }
})();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  translateLinkParam('utm_content');
});
```

Однако для динамически формируемого контента вам придется выполнять данную функцию после каждого изменения содержимого страницы.

Answer (score 0):

в nginx можно изменить так

```
  rewrite ^(.*)?utm_content=(.*)$ $1?utm_content=$2;
```

На Apache2 тоже можно сделать подобным образом. Думаю идея понятна - делать редирект средствами сервера.